# Strange javascript/jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hopefully someone can help me here.

I have a page that displays a list of users in a modal popup. This page can be accessed in two ways, one way you choose Unapproved users and it will open the page, the other way you choose user accounts which will open a popup asking if you have any search criteria such as name, once you have finished there you search and it brings up the page of users.

I have a button on the form to clear any filters. When i run it on the Unapproved users page, it clears the box fine, however if i do it on the form from the other way the code will not empty the textbox and when i try an alert it shows no data. Where as the alert works on the Unapproved route!

Here is the jquery that i am using:

```
    clear: function () {
        //reset filters//
        $('.usersFilterList li').remove();
        $('.userFilterSelect option').show();

        $('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').attr('value', ''); // This line doesn't seem to work properly

        alert($('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').attr('value'));

        //hide filter options
        MSG.showNHide('', '#usersFilterBox');

        //reset modal control buttons
        $('#usersButSaveFilter,#usersButClearFilter').hide();
        $('#usersButFilter').fadeIn();

        usersFilter.refresh(0);
    }
```

Can anyone see if i am doing anything stupid? As i say, it is exactly the same form called from the same MVC action just with the other popup in between.

Apologies if this is confusing, I cannot post anymore code i am afraid. I can assure you that the ID of the textbox is correct though.

Any advice here would be much appreciated as I have been staring at it for hours now...

Cheers,
Gareth

If i right click the second option and run in new tab and run that first pop up as a full page the code will then work! So the problem appears to be that there are two popups.

**SOLVED**

I found a work around of my own, thanks for all your help.

I simply assigned a class and searched for any items with that class and cleared it like so:

```
    $('.jq-clearme').val('');
```

I will close this when i can. I am not allowed yet due to my rep being too low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around of my own, thanks for all your help.

I simply assigned a class and searched for any items with that class and cleared it like so:

```
$('.jq-clearme').val('');
```

I will close this when i can. I am not allowed yet due to my rep being too low.

Answer (score 2):

To change the value of an element (or to retrieve it), accessing the *attribute* is the wrong way to go - it's not synchronized in both directions. What you want is the *property*. While also exposed through `.prop('value'[, newvalue])` the correct way to get/set it with jQuery is `.val([newvalue])`.

To clear the element's value use the following:

```
$('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').val('');
```

To retrieve/show it, use

```
alert($('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').val());
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately it does the same thing, works on the first route but not the second.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal testcase on jsfiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: If i had any clue how to use this I am sure I could, unfortunately i dont have a clue :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use `val()` to get/set the value of the input.

Use without a parameter to get the value:

```
$('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').val();
```

And with a paramater set the value, in this case set it to nothing:

```
$('#UserFilter_SearchTermIncluded').val('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately it does the same thing, works on the first route but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an ajax call involved which might be loading the Javascript you posted twice and hence when called the second time (after the ajax call) it finds a conflict?

As mentioned by others best to use `.val('')` to set a value and `.val()` to get the value. Check in firebug if there are any Javascript errors.

Comment: There is ajax involved yes, so it could well be something like this. Firebug isnt showing any errors.